# Laravel select2 no results found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

recently I run into problem with integration select2 with laravel.

I want to call ajax request to filter users but I get No results found.

I created test files in my localhost:

```
<html>
<head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select class="js-data-example-ajax"></select>

<script>

$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json'
    // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
  }
});
</script>
```

Ajax.php

```
<?php echo "{
  \"results\": [
    {
      \"id\": 1,
      \"text\": \"Option 1\"
    },
    {
      \"id\": 2,
      \"text\": \"Option 2\"
    }
  ]
}";
```

This is running ok but when I use the same script in my laravel blade template I get Nore sult found:

index.blade.php (Note: I have jquery and select2 loaded in head section)

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax"></select>

<script>

    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://localhost/ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json'
            // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a route that resolves `http://localhost/ajax.php`?

Comment: no I dont. I just got it working I added the script into /resources/assets/js/app.js ran npm dev and its working...

Comment: Well, if the url you're ajaxing to doesn't exist there can be no results.

Comment: Well that file was existing on that path. Never mind I solved it

Answer (score 2):

if you want to just run your example in the laravel project you should move the Ajax.php file to your public folder.
and if you want your list to be dynamic not just a static json content you should make a route for function that will generate the select2 elements

**web.php**

```
Route::get('select2list', 'TestController@select2list');
```

**TestController.php**

```
public function select2list()
{
    //generate your list in the way you want
    $temp = '{
      "results": [
           {
              "id": 1,
              "text": "Option 1"
           },
           {
              "id": 2,
              "text": "Option 2"
           }
         ]
        }';
    die(json_decode( $temp ));
}
```

and to load this list in your view you should make this ajax request like this

```
var mySelect2Elements;
$.ajax({
    url: "/select2list",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {

         alert( data );
         mySelect2Elements = data;

    }
}).done(function() {
    $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2(
       { data: mySelect2Elements}
    );
});
```

Comment: the problem was with javascript not with app logic. I had the javascript in blade template when I moved it to app.js and made build it was working

Comment: if there is any error please leave the error message in a comment otherwise if my reply answers your question please accept it

Comment: No it doesnt. As i said problem was in javascript

Comment: can you open the console and tell me what is exactly the error ?

Comment: there was no error in console. I am using laravel webpack and when I included the function into resources/assets/js/app.js and run npm dev it was working